# Postgres multi-column index is taking forever to complete

Tags: postgresql, indexing, query-performance, b-tree-index

I have a table with around 270,000,000 rows and this is how I created it.

```
CREATE TABLE init_package_details AS
    SELECT pcont.package_content_id as package_content_id,
                    pcont.activity_id as activity_id,
                    pc.org_id as org_id,
                    pc.bed_type as bed_type,
                    pc.is_override as is_override,
                    pmmap.package_id as package_id,
                    pcont.activity_qty as activity_qty,
                    pcont.charge_head as  charge_head,
                    pcont.activity_charge as charge,
                    COALESCE(pc.charge,0) - COALESCE(pc.discount,0) as package_charge 
    FROM a pc
                    JOIN b od ON
                                (od.org_id = pc.org_id AND od.status='A')
                    JOIN c pm ON 
                                (pc.package_id=pm.package_id)
                    JOIN d pmmap ON
                                (pmmap.pack_master_id=pm.package_id)
                    JOIN e pcont ON 
                                (pcont.package_id=pmmap.package_id);
```

I need to build index on the `init_package_details` table.

This table is getting created at around 5-6 mins.

I have created btree index like,

```sql
CREATE INDEX init_package_details_package_content_id_idx 
   ON init_package_details(package_content_id);`
```

which is taking 10 mins (**More than the time to create and populate the table itself**)

And, when I create another index like,

```
CREATE INDEX init_package_details_package_act_org_bt_id_idx 
   ON init_package_details(activity_id,org_id,bed_type);
```

It just freezes and taking forever to complete. I waited for around 30 mins before I manually cancelled it.

Below are stats from `iotop -o` if it helps,

- When I created table Averaging around 110-120 MB/s (This is how 270 million rows got inserted in 5-6 mins)
- When I created First Index, It was averaging at around 70 MB/s
- On second index, it is snailing at 5-7 MB/s

Could someone explain Why is this happening? Is there anyway I can speedup the index creations here?

EDIT 1: There are no other connections accessing the table. And, `pg_stat_activity` shows `active` as status throughout the running time. This happens inside a transaction (this is happening between `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`, it contains many other scripts in same `.sql` file).

EDIT 2:

```
 postgres=# show work_mem ;
 work_mem
----------
 5MB
(1 row)

postgres=# show maintenance_work_mem;
 maintenance_work_mem
----------------------
 16MB
```

Comment: Is the table accessed by other sessions/connections? Maybe the CREATE INDEX is just waiting for a lock? You can check `pg_stat_activity` to see if the DDL is waiting for something. In case you turned **off** autocommit: did you properly commit everything?

Comment: No. There are no other sessions accessing the table. pg_stat_activity shows 'active'

Comment: How big is your `work_mem` and `maintenance_work_mem` ? (`show work_mem;`  and `show maintenance_work_mem;` will tell you). Creating the index will need to sort the values and if that is done on disk, this will take a while. Try to increase them as high as possible.

Comment: I've added them in the edit. I am unsure of the figures to be set. If you could help me with some article of this it would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building indexes takes a long time, that's normal.

If you are not bottlenecked on I/O, you are probably on CPU.

There are a few things to improve the performance:

- Set `maintenance_work_mem` very high.
- Use PostgreSQL v11 or better, where several parallel workers can be used.

Comment: Thanks @Laurenz! I've tried setting maintenance_work_mem to 512 MB. Then, the index creation is almost done in 15 mins.